# Bootstrap 4 Container Width Incorrect

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using a Bootstrap 4 "Container" to wrap my footer in.

The Container width does not cover the bottom of the screen as expected. If I change the Container to Container-Fluid it does not work as expected either.

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/1Zero3Tech/6p1rg3ub/3/

```
 <div class="container">
        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 text-left">
                    Some Text On The Left
                </div>
                <div class=" col-6 text-right">
                    Some Text On The Right
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Your `position:absolute` rule is killing Bootstrap

Comment: `.container-fluid` has 15px of padding on either side, you'd need to remover/override that, perhaps with negative margin. - https://jsfiddle.net/zrhmga0v/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`container` or `container-fluid` class should be used to cover the content area, not the width.

So, I have refactored the HTML structure, with this the `footer` will be responsible for the width, not `container` or `container-fluid`. They will be responsible for your content area.

> For convenient, I have added a `fixed` class, which makes footer stick
>   to the bottom of the page but if you don't want sticky footer you can
>   always remove the class.

```css
.footer {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<footer class="footer fixed">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 text-left">
        Some Text On The Left
      </div>
      <div class=" col-6 text-right">
        Some Text On The Right
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both j08691 and Paulie_D are correct. Take out `position: absolute`, and put some negative margins on the parent `.container`. You might also want to experiment with making the parent `.container` sticky to the bottom.